# Translate articles and submit them in other journals

Tags: journals, paper-submission, translations

May I do the following? I have published some academic papers in my mother tongue language in not well known academic journals of my country. Can I translate these papers into English and submit them to other international academic journals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with what you want to do. To translate a work (and subsequently publish it), you need permission from the copyright holder of the original work. Many publishers require you to transfer copyright to them, so you may not have copyright on the works you want to translate any more.

On top of that, journals are interested in work that has not been published before (even if it was in another language).

That is not to say that there is no place for translated works. Some non-english journals regularly publish translations of their articles, and one can sometimes also find translations of important papers in the field. However this is something that is typically done by the publishers.